# How to reference previous parameter in interactive bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, interactive

I'm trying to do something like:

```
mv doc1 $1.html #equivalent to mv doc1 doc1.html
```

but the problem here is that, because I'm in an interactive shell, `$1` refers to the first parameter passed to "bash", which isn't set.

I know I could use:

```
p=doc1; mv $p $p.html
```

but I'm really looking for something more elegant.

Before you respond, please note this is a general question; I'm not looking for workaround to the `mv` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html)

```
mv doc1 !#:1.html
```

should work, but I can't test it now.